# MySQL transpose multiple tables query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to do the following:

I have two different tables:

table_a

| Date | ID | Fieldname_1 | Fieldname_2 | Unit_1 | Percntg_1 | Unit_2 | Percntg_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-01-2021 | 1 | John Doe | Mike High | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0.62 |
| 05-01-2021 | 2 | Eric | Tania steven | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0.32 |
| 12-02-2021 | 3 | Mike High | Harold | 0 | 0.95 | 0 | 0.82 |
| 18-02-2021 | 4 | Liz | Quentin | 2 | 0.51 | 7 | 0.98 |

table_b

| ID | Quantity | Price | Product |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 500 | 250.5 | 4 |
| 2 | 150 | 600 | 2 |
| 3 | 50 | 720 | 3 |
| 4 | 600 | 350 | 4 |

Would I would like to get is this:

| Date | ID | Fieldname | Unit | Percntg | Quantity | Price | Product |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-01-2021 | 1 | John Doe | 3 | 0 | 500 | 250.5 | 4 |
| 01-01-2021 | 1 | Mike High | 0 | 0.62 | 500 | 250.5 | 4 |
| 05-01-2021 | 2 | Eric | 0 | 0 | 150 | 600 | 2 |
| 05-01-2021 | 2 | Tania Steven | 0 | 0.22 | 150 | 600 | 2 |
| 12-02-2021 | 3 | Mike High | 0 | 0.95 | 50 | 720 | 3 |
| 12-02-2021 | 3 | Harold | 0 | 0.82 | 50 | 720 | 3 |
| 18-02-2021 | 4 | Liz | 2 | 0.51 | 600 | 350 | 4 |
| 18-02-2021 | 4 | Quentin | 7 | 0.98 | 600 | 350 | 4 |

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can we instead suggest that you're starting from the wrong place. First normalise your data.

Comment: This is common and can be normalised inline @radocaw . What SQL engine are you using, it can affect the syntax

Comment: @ChrisSchaller OP put `mysql` in title and tag, so I think it should be safe to assume it's `mysql`?

Comment: Cheers, I missed that in the mobile view, used to seeing it at the bottom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can unpivot using `union all` and then `join`:

```
select *
from ((select Date, ID, Fieldname_1 as fieldname, Unit_1 as unit, Percntg_1 as percentg
       from table_a
      ) union all
      (select Date, ID, Fieldname_2 as fieldname, Unit_2 as unit, Percntg_2 as percentg
       from table_a
      )
     ) a join
     table_b b
     using (id);
```

Comment: Well done, beat me to it, the mobile view doesn't notify like the desktop one

Answer (score 0):

First you need to normalised the `table_a`, then it's a simple join on `table_b`:

```
SELECT  ​Date,NormalData.ID,Fieldname,Unit,Percntg,Quantity,Price,Product
​FROM (
    SELECT Date, ID, FieldName_1 AS FieldName, Unit_1 as Unit, percntg_1 AS Percntg
    FROM table_a
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Date, ID, FieldName_2 AS FieldName, Unit_2 as Unit, percntg_2 AS Percntg
) NormalData
LEFT INNER JOIN table_b ON NormalData.Unit = table_b.ID
```

> Notice how the sub query uses a union and we simply select the individual fields.

**Note:** I haven't tested this syntax on MySQL, but hopefully it points you in the right direction